# Is there a way to test a RESTful api without actually running the backend computations in Serenity

Tags: java, rest, api, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I'm attempting to test an api, but this api depends on running other services. Essentially the problem is that I want to test the api, but don't want to actually run those services, they are already tested elsewhere.

Here is a basic breakdown of what we are testing in general terms:

1. I have an api that makes a `foo` I want to test `bar`
2. Part of making `foo` makes the file `bar`
3. I have a lot of very different `foo`'s and a lot of similar `bar`'s
4. I don't want to make a new `foo` every time I want to check the `bar`

I've thought of but haven't come to a conclusion on:

1. Just test `bar` when I make a `foo`(but all the `bar` are in a similar service and probably shouldn't be tested separately)
2. Actually make a `foo` whenever I make a `bar`(time intensive, double testing, bad for Separation of Concerns)
3. Create a fake database of `bar` that the api tests call(requires db changes, not sure of effectiveness of this type of test)
4. Use some sort of Serenity/Cucumber magic

Other Issues:

1. When the tests are run, it's threaded, so I can't guarantee that `foo` occurs before `bar`.

Comment: you want to test a rest-service without running the rest-service?

Comment: essentially there are two services, one service is actually doing computation, the other is simply monitoring that. I want to test the monitor

Comment: then mock the service you're not testing

Comment: i'm using serenity, so I can't do any jUnit mocking, is there a way to mock within serenity, or another service type that I could use(i'm also fairly unfamiliar with this type of testing in general)

Comment: that completely depends on your code.